# React only re-renders modified contenteditable once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, contenteditable

This is a bit of a weird one to reproduce, had to use timeouts to hack it but it does emulate the issue I'm having.

https://jsfiddle.net/mwqyub1v/13/

1) React renders the `div` with `abc123`. **Manipulate this string (add a `4` or something)**

2) After the first timeout, React will remove the content -- **type something in to the box manually now, before the second timer triggers.**.

3) At the second timer, React *does* run the `render` method (note the logging fires) with `this.props.value` as `null`, but the div does not update (it won't remove any text you've typed in since abc123 went away).

I know playing with the contents of a contenteditable can prevent React from being able to manage that content (hence me suppressing the warning). But why does the component update correctly after I've modified text in step 1 above? Furthermore, if the second timer sets `value` to be some other text, as opposed to `null`, then once again the component updates properly.

How can I get this component to always reset the contenteditable contents, even when value is `null`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it's not updated with the second timeout because the virtual dom didn't detect any difference. This will set the innerHTML based on the `props`: https://jsfiddle.net/mwqyub1v/35/.

```
class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.node = React.findDOMNode(this);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.node.innerHTML = this.props.value;
  }

  render() {

    console.log('value', this.props.value);

    return React.createElement('div', {
        contentEditable : true,
      suppressContentEditableWarning : true
    }, this.props.value);

  }

}
```